# Simular um evento de Click sem clicar usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Tenho um projeto aqui com um problema,
estou perto de resolver mas preciso de uma mão de vocês!

Na Home, temos um botão chamado "Coberturas" que ao ser clicado deve ser levado para a página de Empreendimentos.

Nesta página, temos um Plugin do tipo Portfolio-Filter, onde a princípio todos os imóveis são mostrados, e caso o usuário clique em alguma categoria, por ex: 1 dormitório, 2 dormitórios ...... coberturas, então apenas os imóveis deste tipo ficam na tela com um efeito desaparecendo os outros em forma de fadeToggle().

Mas a url não é alterada ao clicar nesses filtros, normalmente um #Categoria aparece na url, mas neste caso não.

Fiz o seguinte:

- No botão Coberturas da Home, eu chamo a URL: http://site .com .br?tipo=coberturas
- Então o jQuery busca na url a string "tipo=coberturas", isso já está ok.
- Agora preciso que quando isso acontecer, forçar um click (não sei se é possível) sem o usuário clicar, no filtro Coberturas.

Dicas??

Segue código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("?tipo=coberturas") > -1) {
       alert("Opa, encontrou.");
       var filtroCoberturas = $('li a[data-filter*="cobertura"]');
       //Agora aqui preciso fazer a LI selecionada ser clicada automáticamente         
    }
});
```

Comment: É possível, como mostra a resposta já postada. Mas se foi você mesmo que criou a ação de clique no botão, pode ser mais elegante fazer de outra maneira.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar `$.trigger('click')`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("?tipo=coberturas") > -1) {
       alert("Opa, encontrou.");
       var filtroCoberturas = $('li a[data-filter*="cobertura"]');
       //executa o evento "click" no elemento 
       filtroCoberturas.trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ou apenas `filtroCoberturas.click()`

Comment: Não funcionou não.. tentei várias coisas aqui também.

Pelo que vi na documentação e em alguns posts do Stackoverflow gringo... não é comum funcionar num <a> e principalmente se o href dele é só '#'.

Estou pesquisando aqui!

Comment: O trigger ali não é em um `a` e sim no `li`. Se o elemento que responde ao click é o `a` você precisa mudar o seletor ali.

Comment: André, desculpe, mas o seletor ali está para o `a` já. Fiz os testes para ver qual seletor estava pegando.

Comment: @Tiago Erro meu! Não tinha reparado. A menos que o `a` tenha sido criado _depois_ deste deste código ter sido executado eu não vejo motivo para o evento click não ser disparado.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro valeu pela ideia do trigger(). Acredito que por questões de segurança do browser o trigger do click do `a` não funcione, segue resposta logo abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente era através do trigger, mas assim:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?tipo=coberturas") > -1) {

    $(document).on('ready simularClique', function() {
        var filtroCoberturas = $('li a[data-filter*="cobertura"]');
        filtroCoberturas.click();
    });
    // Chama a função de clique através do trigger
    $(document).trigger('simularClique');

}
```

Não dava para chamar o clique direto via trigger().

Fui obrigado a fazer o trigger chamar uma função.